# R using waaay more memory than expected

Tags: r

I have an Rscript being called from a java program.  The purpose of the script is to automatically generate a bunch of graphs in ggplot and them splat them on a pdf. It has grown somewhat large with maybe 30 graphs each of which are called from their own scripts.

The input is a tab delimited file from 5-20mb but the R session goes up to 12gb of ram usage sometimes (on a mac 10.68 btw but this will be run on all platforms).

I have read about how to look at the memory size of objects and nothing is ever over 25mb and even if it deep copies everything for every function and every filter step it shouldn't get close to this level.

I have also tried gc() to no avail. If I do gcinfo(TRUE) then gc() it tells me that it is using something like 38mb of ram. But the activity monitor goes up to 12gb and things slow down presumably due to paging on the hd.

I tried calling it via a bash script in which I did ulimit -v 800000 but no good.

What else can I do?

Comment: Please produce a reproducible example - without this it will be nigh impossible to address the issue. If you post the Rscript you are calling, and the java program which calls it, and some example data.

Comment: Does it do that if you only generate one of the thirty graphs? If not, try fifteen. Then try the other fifteen. It might be one of your graphs, or it could be the number of them. Do some more work and find out. Simplify simplify simplify until you can formulate and test a hypothesis. Then, as said, give us a simple reproducible example.

Comment: Good advice so far.  Also I'm not sure where the idea came about the `gc()` is the solution to all problems memory-related.  R calls `gc()` automatically, and it's quite good at it.

Comment: Thanks Spacedman. Sometimes I need a calm voice saying, it's okay, just debug from your base assumptions up.

Answer (score 1):

In the process of making assignments R will always make temporary copies, sometimes more than one or even two. Each temporary assignment will require contiguous memory for the full size of the allocated object.  So the usual advice is to plan to have _at_least_ three time the amount of *contiguous* _memory available. This means you also need to be concerned about how many other non-R programs are competing for system resources as well as being aware of how you memory is being use by R. You should try to restart your computer, run only R, and see if you get success.

An input file of 20mb might expand quite a bit (8 bytes per double, and perhaps more per character element in your vectors) depending on what the structure of the file is. The pdf file object will also take quite a bit of space if you are plotting each point within a large file.

My experience is not the same as others who have commented. I do issue `gc()` before doing memory intensive operations. You should offer code and describe what you mean by "no good". Are you getting errors or observing the use of virtual memory   ... or what?

Comment: Thanks. The comments have been useful. I am debugging the situation effectively now. One issue is that I had a variable number of columns which could grow pretty large with some outliers. So the huge number of NA's were taking up space. One question that I have is does R deep copy data frames that I send as a parameter to functions? If so that is pretty silly IMO.

Comment: @user1816786: wrt. deep copies being silly. Usually R does that only if you *change* the data.frame inside your function. That gives a call-by-value behaviour (i.e. a function cannot change a variable outside its scope). IMHO R is pretty good at finding out when it doesn't need to copy while keeping up the call-by-vale appearance. Call-by-reference is possible via environments and reference classes.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for not posting a more comprehensive description with code. It was fairly long as was the input. But the responses I got here were still quite helpful. Here is how I mostly fixed my problem.

I had a  variable number of columns which, with some outliers got very numerous. But I didn't need the extreme outliers, so I just excluded them and cut off those extra columns. This alone decreased the memory usage greatly. I hadn't looked at the virtual memory usage before but sometimes it was as high as 200gb lol. This brought it down to up to 2gb.

Each graph was created in its own function. So I rearranged the code such that every graph was first generated, then printed to pdf, then rm(graphname).

Futher, I had many loops in which I was creating new columns in data frames. Instead of doing this, I just created vectors not attached to data frames in these calculations. This actually had the benefit of greatly simplifying some of the code.

Then after not adding columns to the existing dataframes and instead making column vectors it reduced it to 400mb. While this is still more than I would expect it to use, it is well within my restrictions. My users are all in my company so I have some control over what computers it gets run on.